# Playing a video in iOS app: audio but no picture

Tags: iphone, video, audio

i want a short video to play in my iphone app. When i use the code below, i only hear the audio and see
the regular view of the app. I want the video to play on top of this view.
What can i do about this?

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"LEADER" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL  *movieURL = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    [theMovie play];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't mix up `MPMoviePlayerController` and `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. When you use `MPMoviePlayerController` use it like this (*typically for embedded videos on the iPad*):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

When you use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` then present the video with `presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:` (*typically for fullscreen videos*).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried replacing the MPMoviePlayerController part with your suggestions but keep getting error all over the place...

Answer (score 0):

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player =
        [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: myURL];
[player.view.frame = self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

The only magic that worked for me was

```
 - (void) playMovie {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
        @"http://www.example.com/video.mp4"];
    MPMoviePlayerController *controller = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
        initWithContentURL:url];

    self.mc = controller; //Super important
    controller.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //Set the size

    [self.view addSubview:controller.view]; //Show the view
    [controller play]; //Start playing
}
```

In Header file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) MPMoviePlayerController* mc;
```

[More Details](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/playing-video-from-a-url-in-ios7/)