# How can I stream only the sound of a video from YouTube?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, stream, youtube

I would like to stream only sound from youtube. I need this for IOS but others can be ok. I have searched on stackoverflow but I couldn't find. Because I don't want to use another software, I want to directly stream only sound of youtube video by code. Also It should work on background.

Comment: This seems to be against the YouTube terms of service, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312179/can-we-play-only-audio-using-youtube-api-for-iphone

Comment: @itstame wrote "MusicPiped for Android claims to do this now, in other words not download the video part of the stream. But how it does it i have no idea, i would like to have it happen on my Linux system."

Answer (score 7):

Flashgot (for Firefox) has a way to download only the audio of a Youtube video. It exposes links to the audio that looks like this:

https://r3---sn-p5qlsu7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=887ce37c617a3225&itag=141&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&gcr=ca&ratebypass=yes&mime=audio%2Fmp4&gir=yes&clen=4012348&lmt=1409362978343745&dur=125.828&signature=0A00B9B16BB6EF3192DF33EEF9B2AB67F66F501F.0B649D407144B914A7CC7BE00E795B5BD1B9D932&upn=VFAbXgDGSU8&key=cms1&fexp=900718%2C924231%2C924637%2C927622%2C930809%2C931354%2C932404%2C9405454%2C941004%2C943917%2C945066%2C947209%2C947218%2C948124%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C955301%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201&sver=3&ip=24.235.37.181&ipbits=0&expire=1419930614&sparams=clen,dur,expire,gcr,gir,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,requiressl,source&cmbypass=yes&req_id=3eb2c618c54ca3ee&redirect_counter=2&cms_redirect=yes&mm=26&ms=tsu&mt=1419909012&mv=m

OK, so that is a very big link. This is the same link dissected into pieces:

```
https://r3---sn-p5qlsu7d.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=887ce37c617a3225
&itag=141
&source=youtube
&requiressl=yes
&gcr=ca
&ratebypass=yes
&mime=audio/mp4 #Here's where audio only is specified.
&gir=yes
&clen=4012348
&lmt=1409362978343745
&dur=125.828
&signature=0A00B9B16BB6EF3192DF33EEF9B2AB67F66F501F.0B649D407144B914A7CC7BE00E795B5BD1B9D932
&upn=VFAbXgDGSU8
&key=cms1
&fexp=900718,924231,924637,927622,930809,931354,932404,9405454,941004,943917,945066,947209,947218,948124,952302,952605,952901,955301,957103,957105,957201
&sver=3
&ip=24.235.37.181 #Oh, look. My IP address.
&ipbits=0
&expire=1419930614
&sparams=clen,dur,expire,gcr,gir,id,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,ms,mv,ratebypass,requiressl,source
&cmbypass=yes
&req_id=3eb2c618c54ca3ee
&redirect_counter=2
&cms_redirect=yes
&mm=26
&ms=tsu
&mt=1419909012
&mv=m
```

Very interesting. This enables Flashgot to download only the audio and skip the video, thus saving bandwidth. I'm missing details, like how Flashgot created this link, but if Flashgot has a way to do it, it stands to reason that other HTTP clients could do it too.

Comment: If an external media player like VLC, SMPlayer or Clementine is added in the Flashgot list, it can be started to play the audio stream **without** downloading it

Comment: Wow, cool! I didn't know that! Most in-browser players are shit due to high levels of javascript.

Comment: also, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/229787/32012, http://stackoverflow.com/a/32613680/4098390,

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. The data stream that you receive from youtube includes both video/audio streams.

What you do with the data, it's up to you. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5337900/176769) has interesting info on the subject.

Comment: Well, How can I get all data that includes both video/audio streams?

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to download a youtube video (retrieve the proper url and download de data)? Because this is entirely different question from the one you asked and should be done in a separate thread.

Comment: uhhh not exactly true.  I'm listening to a live stream  right now that provides both audio and video.  And for the record the audio and video are separate streams.

Comment: @Chris Back in 2012 it wasn't possible. ;) See how old this answer is?!

Comment: @karlphillip yeah apparently my AOL keyword searching isn't as useful as it once was.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Youtube API blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html), the only options you have of playing youtube on iOS is to link to the video (and have the internal YouTube app play the video), or link from a UIWebView and play from there. 
 **Audio-only playback is not supported**.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a MPMoviePlayerController and hide it's view.

Comment: I believe so but one trick the user has to do is hit the home button. The audio stops then they have to double tap the home button, swipe to the media controls and hit play. I don't know if there is a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

Using Audacity software, you could record the audio played on your computer from any source. Since Audacity is open source and you can find open source browsers, you could combine them and get the audio from youtube. Of course its a lot of work, but I am only saying it could be possible unlike others.

Comment: You could also run out of disk space doing this too .

Have you ever filled a disk on a running system before?

That's a treat  let me tell you.

Answer (score 1):

### In Linux:

- **mps-youtube** a CLI solution. More details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229791/32012).
- **VLC** can do that too if started without video - more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229790/32012).
- **mplayer** can be used with the command `mplayer -novideo URL`
- **mpv** can be used with the command `mpv --no-video URL`
- **Youtube Viewer**, a CLI video player can be also used as indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/229812/32012).

### A cross-platform solution:

As indicated in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27699302/4098390) **the Flashgot addon for Firefox** can identify in order to download an audio of a Youtube video. It will display a list of available streams for each video.

The idea is to start the youtube stream in an external player, but to be able to **select only the audio stream with the Flashgot addon in Firefox** by adding the external player as Flashgot "downloader" (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169410/47206)) and then, after starting the youtube video in Firefox, using Flashgot to play only the audio stream by going to 'Available formats/DASH (separate audio and video tracks)'

[[image]

and select the specific audio track.

[[image]

Multimedia players can be assigned in Flashgot  instead of a downloader, like VLC or SMPlayer, as most video players seem able to do the job (in Linux; for Windows, see below update); or even audio players like Clementine, although some audio players may not work.

It will start after a few seconds, some players after more than others. The fastest in Linux seems to be **SMPlayer** .

**UPDATE**:

- Flashgot has to be up to date.
- In Windows, Flashgot seems to display some audio streams in a different location than in the above image, that is already on the first list (before the DASH list). SMPlayer works the best AFAICT. VLC works, but not with all the audio streams listed by Flashgot. Clementine, Foobar2000 and XMPlay failed. It may be an overall-Windows codecs problem. MPC-HC starts but doesn't buffer correctly and stops long before it should.

Comment:  for you using `mpv` works right out of the box  for me. none of the other CLI based utilities worked as intended.

Comment: @Chris - It is something that might be corrected in SMTube in a later update, but I can confirm that for the moment (12 March 2018) the audio only feature with SMPlayer is not working.

Answer (score 1):

There are **separate streams** for *audio* and *video*. This is by default in mp4 to flash conversion.

You can get the combined stream in flash format or separate in mp4 form.

Exemple: 
[Headphones Stereo Test (HD)][youtube.com/watch?v=ZjAQylVPU3I]

contain

[the flash stream][youtube.com/v/ZjAQylVPU3I]

containing the combination of 
[audio stream](https://r3---sn-gqn-unge.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?c=web&clen=485306&cpn=yj9rdXWd18Eo2hV7&cver=as3&dur=30.511&expire=1466398131&fexp=3300100%2C3300134%2C3300161%2C3312381%2C3313263%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9431012%2C9432364%2C9432369%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9437066%2C9437553%2C9438663%2C9439652&gir=yes&id=o-AP3QO22uiT3u9nsCaAxXDaOF5V_aN1NlDADwSae6TMkU&initcwndbps=2872500&ip=0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A1&ipbits=0&itag=140&keepalive=yes&key=yt6&lmt=1388261170958562&mime=audio%2Fmp4&mm=31&mn=sn-gqn-unge&ms=au&mt=1466376153&mv=m&pl=40&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&signature=84062AB04F428FF1EED1FCCA7987A777220CAD0E.A76448ACA6F66BFFB6C1327607A34E7004BD3377&source=youtube&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&sver=3&upn=IVssJgkQnC0&ir=1&rr=12) and [video stream](https://r5---sn-c0q7lnes.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?c=web&clen=247668&cpn=yj9rdXWd18Eo2hV7&cver=as3&dur=30.400&expire=1466398131&fexp=3300100%2C3300134%2C3300161%2C3312381%2C3313263%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9431012%2C9432364%2C9432369%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9437066%2C9437553%2C9438663%2C9439652&gir=yes&id=o-AP3QO22uiT3u9nsCaAxXDaOF5V_aN1NlDADwSae6TMkU&ip=0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A1&ipbits=0&itag=134&keepalive=yes&key=cms1&lmt=1388261164988130&mime=video%2Fmp4&pl=40&ratebypass=yes&requiressl=yes&signature=764F842ACD3B89124F6F14B9984AE6B7D6FBF018.09CB53BA6120A745A8E1F0DF36309D6B3404D1FC&source=youtube&sparams=clen,dur,expire,gir,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source,upn&sver=3&upn=IVssJgkQnC0&redirect_counter=1&req_id=b9bade61241ca3ee&cms_redirect=yes&mm=30&mn=sn-c0q7lnes&ms=nxu&mt=1466377086&mv=m) in mp4 format.

*I'm sorry but the links will not work because they are customized based on ip , expire data , and other things.

To get these links i used uBlock origin for chrome because it has the logger function showing all connections made to server.
search for : mime=video and you can see all links then remove the range to get full length. Same with mime=audio and also you can use that for stream in other flash players but **it is against the Terms of Service**.

Comment: Did this (the fact that audio and video streams are now seperate) change over the last few years?